# How do I restore my .bash_profile?

Tags: terminal, bash

I've accidentally overwritten my `~/.bash_profile` file.

Does anyone have a "sample" one I could copy, or know where I might be able to find one?

Comment: A good time to mention that [GitHub](http://github.com) is an excellent place to store your dotfile customizations. For an example of how to do this see: http://sursolid.com/managing-home-dotfiles-with-git-and-github

Comment: Tip: Use Time Machine to make regular backups of your files so you can recover them if accidentally deleted or edited. The single best investment you can make in your computer is a backup plan.

Comment: Just FYI, I don't think os x has a "default" .bash_profile.

Comment: This really could have been answered by google ("sample bash_profile"). The 3rd hit provides a rather massively complete sample: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/sample-bashrc.html

Answer (score 12):

If your terminal window is still open, you can save the current environment settings to rebuild.  The recovered file will contain more information than you may have defined yourself, so remove the parts you don't need:

Defined vars and functions:

```
$ declare > .bash_profile.recovered
```

Aliases:

```
$ alias >> .bash_profile.recovered
```

Answer (score 3):

Search for dot_files in Google or [Github](https://github.com/search?q=dot_files&type=Everything&repo=&langOverride=&start_value=1) if you like a sample one.

If you like to restore it, you could try to get it from your TimeMachine backup (if present)

Comment: or any other backup - if no backup start producing one now  before doing anything else

Answer (score 3):

There is a backup located at:

```
/etc/skel/.bash_profile
```

Just copy it over your current file.

Comment: Might be worth to add that this is the standard template, so any changes the user made to his local `.bash_profile` will not be reflected in it.

Comment: As of macOS Yosemite (10.10) this appears to no longer be true.  It is the standard arrangement on other Unices, but I can no longer find the skeleton file for new users in the file system.

Answer (score 3):

*This solution only works if you have a terminal open that have the old .bash_profile loaded in it.*

1. **Recover the aliases**:
   Run this in terminal `alias` to print out all aliases and manually paste them to .bash_profile
2. **Recover the PATH**: Print PATH using `echo $PATH`. Manually paste it to the bash_profile in this format:

```
export PATH="my_old_paths_string_that_echoed_in_this_step:$PATH"
```

3. **Recover the functions**: Print functions using `declare -F | grep -v 'declare -f _'`. This will print the bash functions that don't start with `_`, which are usually the ones you define in the bash_profile. If you remember that you defined some functions starting with `_`, then you can remove the grep. Okay. This will give you the names of all the functions. For each function, do this:

```
declare -f my_precious_function1
```

This should give you the definition of the function. And then you copy paste it to .bash_profile. Doing this manually will allow you to skip copying some functions like deactivate etc that were not defined in .bash_profile.

4. **Recover the exports**: `export -p` is the command to list all exports in current session. Run it in new terminal and safe terminal and use python's set difference to list exports missing in the new terminal. Once you have the list, replace `declare -x` with `export` and copy pasta.

That's all I put in bash_profile, alias,functions and PATH. If you have more stuff you can recover it manually by finding your way around. Hope this helps.

Before closing your safe terminal, make sure that your things are working in a new terminal, maybe try the `declare -F` command in the new terminal or some other aliases. I'm not gonna close my safe terminal for days.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to recover it using [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk).

If that doesn't work, type:

```
x56~:$ alias >> ~/.bash_profile
```

and

```
x56:~$ echo "PATH=$PATH" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

to at least recover your PATH and aliases, which you can paste in your new profile file.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is what revision control is for. There is no way to undo modifications, while deletes **through finder** are actually moves to the trash.

Use TimeMachine in the future. Aside from this, it will also give you piece of mind when your current hard drive dies. I know people facing this problem now and if they only invested $30-$50 into a backup hdd, the problems would not happen. I recommend you just learn from this and back up using timemachine periodically.

[Github](http://github.com) as mentioned by *Ian C* is a great place to back your dotfiles, also you can find [dotfiles](https://github.com/search?type=Everything&language=&q=dotfiles&repo=&langOverride=&x=0&y=0&start_value=1) from others'. Version control to the rescue here, don't know how many times it saved me, but definitely more than I can remember. The advantage of TimeMachine is that it also does version control, problem is that its stored by snapshot time, not logical version.

Good luck.

Comment: Time Machine just saved my day. I second this strategy, as someone who likes gnarly command-line aliases that sometimes are missing a backslash and ruin everything.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use Terminal to access your `~/.bash_profile` (e.g. it's corrupted) you can use [BBEdit](http://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/) or any other GUI editor that can open files from a location and open your corrupted file in order to fix it.

BTW. if you know the location and name of any hidden file, this method can be used to open it (assuming it is a text based file).

Answer (score 0):

This method works only if you saved the `bash_profile` file to a point where you want to go back in TextEdit, doesn't work if edited using vi or nano (thanks to [@nohillside](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/9058/nohillside) for pointing this out). You can open the file using TextEdit (for ex: `open ~/.bash_profile`) and click on `File -> Revert To -> Browse All Versions...` and then select the version you want to revert back to.

[image: An image displaying the above procedure]

Comment: Might be work mentioning that this only works for changes applied with TextEdit (changes applied with `vi` or `nano` will not be versioned).

Answer (score -1):

I found this website that has two example of the files of bash_profile and bashrc.

https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/sample-bashrc.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).