# How to restore my deleted .bash_profile?

Tags: macos, bash

I have deleted my .bash_profile with rm command and copied another one to use. But now i remember there is some PATH thing in the previous file :(. Can i find the deleted .bash_profile in some place like Trash?

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/26028/how-do-i-restore-my-bash-profile

Comment: Possible recovery by /etc/skel/.bash_profile

Comment: Can't you recover it from your backup?

Comment: @Buscar웃 i can not find skel folder under /etc :(

Comment: @patrix no backup:(.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do `rm` on a file, it is immediately unlinked from the file system and gone for good.

The Trash is a Finder Idiom that is not available in a unix terminal session. The only way to restore your file is by restoring it from a backup.

Comment: you means if there is no backup, then cannot restore it?

Comment: No. It is (most probably) gone. The data may still be on the disk, but then we are talking data recovery. This in turn will only yield a result if the disk was taken offline immediately. If it was written to for an extended time the data will have been overwritten by new data.