# Why has my .bash_profile file suddenly disappeared and no non standard terminal commands work?

Tags: terminal, bash

My home directory now appears as a link and my `.bash_profile` file isn't in the `/users/myusername` folder?  Where did it go?  What happened?  Commands such as `flutter` and `dart` no longer work but built in commands such as `ls` and `cd` do.

Comment: What do you mean by "the folder"? Are you talking about `/bin/`?

Comment: I'm still fairly new to macs so please bear with me!  I thought that .bash_profile lives in the home folder?  Anyway, something bad has happened!  and I can't run any of my commands nor open bash profile; I did have an alias for my bash profile though so possibly I'm going to the wrong place...but I still can't find it.

Comment: If I do `vi ~/.bash_profile` it creates a new file

Comment: @unbeatable101 any ideas of what could have happend? There are a couple of files in `/bin/` but not my .bash_profile file.  I think the /bin/ is the trash folder right?  What could have happened?

Comment: @atreeon /bin/ is a folder containing some of the **bin**aries, or executables that you can run via terminal. Do you have a backup where you can restore your bash_profile?

Comment: @At0mic no backup unfortunately (well, one that is 6 months old).  Why would it have been removed?

Comment: @atreeon it shouldn't have been removed, unless you or some rogue program deleted it by accident.

Comment: @At0mic and it should just be in /Users/myname I have a .bash_history there.  I think it could have been a rogue program possibly.  Visual Studio Code restarted and asked me for some additional permissions that I didn't quite understand but I may have stupidly clicked yes to it...possibly it was that

Comment: @At0mic the funny thing is that I think my terminal prompt is different too.  I can't remember what it looked like previously but it didn't used to say both my computer name and my username

Comment: @At0mic where abouts is your bash_profile located please?

Comment: Paths file, should that have included my flutter directory?  https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#update-your-path  Why does that no longer have my flutter directory in there?

Comment: @atreeon oh I misunderstood, I thought you were saying you didn't have bash installed, not the that the profile was missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.bash_profile` includes some `export PATH=...`, aliases and custom functions.  If the file no longer exists or has been moved then those commands will no longer work.  The default `/bin` commands such as `ls` and `cd` won't be affected.

My file was moved (possibly by a problem with Visual Studio Code).

There is no automatic backup of this file but this may help
[How do I restore my .bash_profile?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/26028/how-do-i-restore-my-bash-profile/322183)

In my instance luckily my bash profile file had been moved.  The reason I couldn't find it was that 'finder' does not find hidden files (!).  Doing a simple terminal `find` found the file for me.

```
sudo find . -name ".bash_profile"
```

Comment: You shouldn't need `sudo`  for this.

Comment: there were a couple of folders that showed a permissions error without it.  I agree the file would never have been in those folders however the output was more readable without those messages displayed so found it helpful